# adding sound to uibutton

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play a sound when a uibutton is pressed..

this is my code

```
-(IBAction) playSound:(id)sender{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SQUEEK" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];

}
```

this is the output when the button is pressed

```
2012-07-13 16:41:02.803 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:02.811 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:03.389 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:03.396 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:03.409 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:03.417 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:03.431 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-07-13 16:41:03.440 squeek[1475:12103] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

the IBAction is hooked up to the UIButton with the touch up inside feature, also I have added the avfoundation framework.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is exactly duplicate as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean

Comment: nope it dose not work on the device.... I have tried but for some reason just dose not want to play on the device.

Comment: Try adding Security.framework...According to you log,it may work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HurkNburkS

You just need a little more search in Stack Overflow before asking the same question. Whatever check the below question and try the solutions given in that.

[Sound not playing with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963230/sound-not-playing-with-avaudioplayer)

[Supported Audio file formats in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone)

Check out your audio format could be a problem or your "`theAudio`" instance should be deallocated.

Try like this and print your error...

```
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                 initWithContentsOfURL:url
                 error:&error];
if (error)
{
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", 
              [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```