# AVAudioPlayer Not Working upon SpriteKit Scene Loading

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, swift3, xcode8

I was struggling hardcore with a simple task: Play an audio file in the background when a SpriteKit scene loads.

I copied an audio file named "Test Song.wav" into my project and it was also found in my assets when I look under "Build Phases" > "Copy Bundle Resources" (which was what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963230/sound-not-playing-with-avaudioplayer) suggested to check for)

My code compiled just fine, and my [ring/silent switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer) was correctly turned to ring, but the audio didn't play when the scene loaded.

I'm using

- Xcode Version 8.0 beta
- iPhone 6S Plus running iOS 10 Beta 1

Here was my broken code:

```
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let path = Bundle.main().pathForResource("Test Song", ofType: "wav") {

        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)

        let songPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)

        songPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0

        songPlayer.prepareToPlay()

        songPlayer.play()

        }
    }
}
```

Note: I learned that in Swift 3.0, AVAudioPlayer's init() method no longer accepted the NSError parameter, so this code **DOES NOT** compile:

```
var error:NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your moderation efforts, and you are technically correct that this is a duplicate. I'm not trying to argue: I'm genuinely curious how this site works. With that in mind: I can't help but wonder why my post can't stand on its own without being downvoted for not being useful. I made it a "Q&A" style post so nobody's time was wasted in needing/trying to answer it, it is written in Swift 3.0 and for iOS 10, and I cite all my sources. If I didn't know the post you linked to existed, how was I to know to contribute a comment to that post instead of making my own post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this website](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/07/06/how-to-fix-the-common-no-sound-from-avplayer-avaudioplayer-problem-in-ios-swift-programming/) I learned that my problem was the scope of my `AVAudioPlayer` object.

Here is the working code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var songPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let path = Bundle.main().pathForResource("Test Song", ofType: "wav") {

            let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)

            songPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)

            songPlayer?.numberOfLoops = 0 //This line is not required if you want continuous looping music

            songPlayer?.prepareToPlay()

            songPlayer?.play()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which website are you talking about? The link is missing from your answer.