# Make beep sound when receive push notification

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing an chat app in which user can send and receive messages.I done it through push notification.I store all messages in table,So i display all send and receive mesages when user selects a contact.By default push notification making sound when app is closed.How do i add beep sound when app is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate for this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
      //create an audio player and play the sound
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i add default push notification sound with audio player?.

Comment: @user2003416: You need to add a sound like that to bundle and play it or you can use this example (System default)

Comment: @user2003416: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856896/couldnt-play-system-sound-after-switching-to-ios-5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831671/playing-system-sound-without-importing-your-own,https://gist.github.com/zoul/205857

Comment: I do not know basics of audio player.basic example will be helpful